# Link to a saved interactive report

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have several saved queries in an interactive report (IR). How can I generate a link to any particular saved report in the IR?

Comment: And, your question is what, exactly?  Please provide specifics:  What are you trying to do?  With what version of Oracle on what platform?  We are not mind readers.

Comment: @MarkJ.Bobak, have not you seen an answer?

Comment: Not only have I not seen an answer, I haven't even seen a question.  It doesn't matter now, since it's been closed.

Comment: May be you dont understand question?

Comment: I think, while poorly worded, this is a good question. I've tried to reword it, hopefully it can be resurrected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23903_01/doc/doc.41/e21674/bldapp_rpt.htm#BABEJEBJ

> You can link to saved primary default, alternative default and public
>   reports using IR_REPORT_[report_alias] in the request value of the
>   URL.
>
> The following examples demonstrate how to link to a primary report
>   (report_alias=12345):
>
> This example links to a primary report:
>
> f?p=100:1:&APP_SESSION.:IR_REPORT_12345
>
> This example links, resets,
>   and clears primary report settings:
>
> f?p=100:1:&APP_SESSION.:IR_REPORT_12345::RIR,CIR:
>
> This example links,
>   resets, and clears primary report settings. It additionally creates a
>   ENAME = 'KING' filter on the primary report:
>
> f?p=100:1:&APP_SESSION.:IR_REPORT_12345::RIR,CIR:IR_ENAME:KING

Comment: How can I make such link for private saved report?

Comment: I'd say you'd need to know the report alias for it - and obviously only the person who owns the saved report would be able to use it.

Comment: I can't get alias for privately saved report - there is no control for inputting the alias on settings page and REPORT_ALIAS column value in APEX_APPLICATION_PAGE_IR_RPT view is null. And yes, I do need to show that report only for person who owns that report.

Comment: I also took a look, but afaik there is no way to set/get a private report. Like you said, when you query apex_application_page_ir_rpt you can see the private ones have no alias and not even a url example. You can try and select a report through javascript on-load of the page, that's the only way i can see it work for private reports. Or you can let them save public reports, remove the dropdown from the IR, and provide an own select list based on apex_application_page_ir_rpt where you filter by user.

Comment: @Tom, how can I select saved report via javascript?