# Oracle APEX opening a already saved user report

Tags: oracle-apex

I have some saved reports for a page say Employees page.  For example I have saved reports(created by applying some filters,  press Save and give name) like `Report_employees_for_dept_10`,`Report_employees_for_dept_20`, `Report_employees_for_dept_30`
I want to have 3 buttons in another page for each of above report.  When I press button related to "`Report_employees_for_dept_10`".  It should open the saved report named `Report_employees_for_dept_10`.  I can go to the Employees page.  It is showing the last viewed saved report not the one we want.

Can you please explain me how to get the control of IR reports and open the right report.

Thanks,
S.Ravichandran

Comment: What kind of saved reports: are these private?

Comment: yes these are private reports.

Answer (score 0):

See this question: [Link to a saved interactive report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9214426/link-to-a-saved-interactive-report)
Summary: no, it is not possible to link private reports. Unlike public reports, there are no aliases and thus no way to select a private one through a url. You would need to make your reports public.